# PHP mkdir() won't work on Mac OS X even if folder permissions are 777

Tags: php, macos, nginx, mkdir

I'm facing a strange issue. I cannot get `mkdir()` to work on Mac OS X in a directory that is under my home, using nginx + php70-fpm webserver. nginx and php-fpm are installed from [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts). Coming from the Linux world, I have tried the following:

Edit `/opt/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add the `user myusername` directive and reload nginx, but no success. The server won't even start.

Through the `get info` menu option, give permission to the folder I want to write to to `everyone`, but no success.

From the console, [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/) the folder, but no success.

Is there something I am missing?

Code:

```
    if(!file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds . $_SESSION["lid"] . $ds)) {
        // No directory, so create it
        if(mkdir(dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds . $_SESSION["lid"] . $ds, 0777, true)) {
            die("Folder creation failed");
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As an observation, after doing this you may face issues with phpMyAdmin saying incorrect permissions are applied. Therefore, some may find it useful to grand everyone "Read & Write" access only to the htdocs folder, or better yet, the specific folder for the project, not the whole XAMPP folder.

Here is the solution:

1. Open the applications folder
2. Locate the XAMPP folder
3. right-click, and get info (as described above)
4. In the pop-up window, locate the 'sharing & permission' section
5. Click the 'locked' padlock symbol
6. Enter the administrator password
7. Change 'Everyone' permissions to read & write
8. In the get info window still, select the 'cog' icon' drop down
   option at the very bottom and select 'Apply to enclosed items'.

   This will adjust the permission across all sub-folders as well.
9. Re-lock the padlock symbol
10. Close the 'Get Info' window.

The task is complete. This will now allow you to make directories.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. I'm not sure if your problem is the same as mine but I changed the permissions on the root folder to 777 and then everything worked fine.

Comment: What is that "root folder"?